# Where to install Auto Keras as getting error on pip

Tags: python, pip, auto-keras

as per [autokeras](https://autokeras.com/) website
I am trying to install auto keras

I run this command

```
pip install autokeras
```

on Python 3.7.0 command prompt but I am getting this error

```
>>> pip install autokeras
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install autokeras
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: According to the linked website it only works with Python 3.6

Comment: `pip` is not a python command. It's a CLI tool. Run it in your shell.

Comment: @EliKorvigo i tied from windows command prompt but got this error 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @SebastianE it doesn't have anything to do with Python itself (and 3.7 is backwards compatible with 3.6).

Comment: @asmgx which means you don't have it installed. It requires installation.

Comment: @EliKorvigo i did install it, i downloaded get-pip.py and installed it using python get-pip.py and it was successful

Comment: I got it working. i used this link it helped   https://matthewhorne.me/how-to-install-python-and-pip-on-windows-10/

Comment: You should consider installing miniconda and using virtual environments to save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: @EliKorvigo i have anaconda, but how can i use it to install pip?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: @asmgx `conda create -n my_new_environment python=3.7` creates an environment called "my_new_environment" with `pip` out of the box. You can then activate this environment (on a Unix-like OS) by executing `conda activate my_new_environment` or `source activate my_new_environment ` depending on your conda version and configurations. I would think it shouldn't be significantly different on Windows.